# Response.BinaryWrite Div

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to write PDF to a div from DataBase i.e. Retrieve a Byte[] from Database and Reponse.BinaryWrite to a div.

We do similar thing for Images using src = "anotherpage.aspx" where image is written on anotherpage.

Is it possible with PDF without using IFrame?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to extract the contents of a PDF to text and write to the DIV? And what makes this question related to SharePoint 2010?

Comment: That div resides in a WebPart. Makes more sense on StackOverflow probably. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably more appropriate for a site like Stack Overflow.  That having been said, check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848679/reading-a-binary-file-and-using-response-binarywrite.